# How to add a number to every header, unique to each file in a directory?

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics

I have a directory of hundreds of multi-FASTA files.

In each file headers follow the same naming logic, such as:

`>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]`

where:

`>` is a beginning of each header

`Bubo_bubo` is a species name (and it is the same as a name of a FASTA file, here: `Bubo_bubo.fasta`)

`c5_g1_i1` is a specification of a sequence and all other characters are additional information about a specific sequence

What I want to do is to add the same number to each header in a particular file, between species name and other information about this file, to get sth like:

`>Bubo_bubo_001_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]`

I want that number to be different for each file. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: ````Bubo_bubo```` will be different for different file name.. right?

Comment: yes @stack0114106, correctly!

Comment: can I assume that after the second underscore, the specific sequence part appears

Comment: yes! this is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little verbose, but I think it will do the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}filename!=FILENAME{++uniquenumber;filename=FILENAME}/^>/{printf "%s_%s_%03d_%s_%s_%s\n", $1,$2,uniquenumber,$3,$4,$5 > FILENAME"_updated";next}{print $0 > FILENAME"_updated"}' *
```

That will:

1. Before processing (`BEGIN{}`) set the field separator to underscore.
2. If the variable `filename` is not equal to the current file we are processing `FILENAME` then increment the `uniquenumber` variable by 1 and set the `filename` variable to the current filename we are processign `FILENAME`
3. If the line starts with a `>` (`/^>/`)
4. Then print out the line adding the unique number padded to three characters using leading 0's: (`printf "%s_%s_%03d_%s_%s_%s\n", $1,$2,uniquenumber,$3,$4,$5`)
5. Redirect that output the same filename, but with an `_updated` suffix (you'll now have a new file with the change. And continue to the next line in the file (`> FILENAME"_updated";next`)
6. If you are still here then we are on a regular line. Just print it to the same `_updated` file: `{print $0 > FILENAME"_updated"}`
7. Do this for all files in this directory `*`

Example:

```
~/fasta$ ls
file1  file2  file3
~/fasta$ cat *
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
blah
blah
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
blah
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
foo
bar
foo
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
foo
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]

_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
whatevfs
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
asd
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
~/fasta$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}filename!=FILENAME{++uniquenumber;filename=FILENAME}/^>/{printf "%s_%s_%03d_%s_%s_%s\n", $1,$2,uniquenumber,$3,$4,$5 > FILENAME"_updated";next}{print $0 > FILENAME"_updated"}' file*
~/fasta$ cat *updated
>Bubo_bubo_001_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
blah
blah
>Bubo_bubo_001_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
blah
>Bubo_bubo_002_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
foo
bar
foo
>Bubo_bubo_002_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
foo
>Bubo_bubo_002_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]

_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
whatevfs
>Bubo_bubo_003_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
asd
>Bubo_bubo_003_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
```

Comment: your command works perfectly! also, big thanks for your amazing explanation. I didn't know that instead of using a loop I can simply add '*' in the end to treat all files in the directory in the same way. I have to admit that awk syntax is very tricky for me, but with that explanation I really start to understand it.

Comment: If you are going to be monkeying with these types of files, `awk` is definitely worth learning. I've seen quite a lot of folks come through here trying to modify fasta files and `awk` always seems to do the job nicely.

Comment: I was looking for some sort of tutorial on the basics, but didn't really find anything besides an actual manual. Can you recommend any tutorial worth checking out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using Perl

Input files

```
$ ls -1 Bubo_bubo*fasta
Bubo_bubo.fasta
Bubo_bubo2.fasta
Bubo_bubo3.fasta
Bubo_bubo4.fasta

$ cat Bubo_bubo.fasta
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
a b c

$ cat Bubo_bubo2.fasta
>Bubo_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
d e f

$ cat Bubo_bubo3.fasta
>Bubo_bubo3_chihoig len=134 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
g h i

$ cat Bubo_bubo4.fasta
>Bubo_bubo4_wrwklk_gjf len-133 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
p q r
```

Solution:

Perl -i replaces all the files in-place.

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe ' if($.==1) { $y=sprintf("%03d",++$x); s/^>((.+?)_(.+?))_/>\1_${y}_/ } close(ARGV) if eof ' Bubo_bubo*fasta
```

Output:

```
$ cat Bubo_bubo.fasta
>Bubo_bubo_001_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
a b c

$ cat Bubo_bubo2.fasta
>Bubo_bubo_002_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
d e f

$ cat Bubo_bubo3.fasta
>Bubo_bubo3_003_chihoig len=134 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
g h i

$ cat Bubo_bubo4.fasta
>Bubo_bubo4_004_wrwklk_gjf len-133 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
p q r
```

Comment: thank you @stack0114106! does it mean that if I have more than one header in a fasta file should I add `g` in the end of  `s/^>((.+?)_(.+?))_/>\1_${y}_/`?

Comment: here g is not needed, because already we are filtering for the first line ($.==1) and we are anchoring with start of the expression as ````^>````